# Regression model Giving the same prediction for all new inputs until i load the model again

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, regression, cross-validation, accuracy

I have build a regression model that has some decent accuracy measures.

I have pickled it and loading it another project. However it is producing the same predictions every time when i pass new elements. After again i reloaded the model and gave the same set of new inputs then it gave new predictions and again it is producing the same outputs again and again though i have passing different inputs. This scenario repeating until i reload the model again.

The algorithm i have used Linear Regression, RandomForest Regressor.

Is there any cache issue or object defaulting it to first inputs. i was confused to understand the behavior of it. how can i proceed further.

Please anyone can suggest me. it would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Edit (add code from comments)

```
import pickle # Dump the trained model with Pickle 

model_filename = 'lrmodel.pkl' # # Open the file to save as pkl file 
model_pkl = open(model_filename, 'wb') 
pickle.dump(model, model_pkl, protocol=2) # Close the pickle instances 
model_pkl.close() #Load the Model 
model_pkl = open(model_filename, 'rb') 
model = pickle.load(model_pkl) #Prediction of Model model_pred = 
model.predict(df_test_model)
```

Comment: Can you please include your code as well? It's not possible to identify the source of your issue if we don't see how you use that model.

Comment: `import pickle`  `# Dump the trained model with Pickle`  `model_filename = 'lrmodel.pkl'`  `# # Open the file to save as pkl file`  `model_pkl = open(model_filename, 'wb')`  `pickle.dump(model, model_pkl, protocol=2)`  `# Close the pickle instances`  `model_pkl.close()`  `#Load the Model`  `model_pkl = open(model_filename, 'rb')`  `model = pickle.load(model_pkl)`  `#Prediction of Model`  `model_pred = model.predict(df_test_model)`

Comment: Can you clarify a few things? Which algorithm are you using? Is it linear regression or a random forest? Those are different. Also, can you show the code where you built the model, not just the code where you saved the model? Additionally giving sample inputs/outputs would be helpful.